# 'As' or 'for' benchmark in a table

Tags: prepositions

I have a table which has the following entry which is in brackets:

"(conventional control **as** benchmark)"

Can I write it like this or would you rather use 'for benchmark'? Unfortunately the space is limmited in the table and I do not want to have another linebreak. This is why I can't write 'serves as bechmark'.

I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: Conventional control (benchmark)

Comment: Thanks Jim for your answer. I forgot to mention that the statement itself is in brackets. I adjusted this in the original post.

Comment: I like either "as" or the parentheses suggested by @Jim. "For benchmark" could be confusing, because it almost sounds like you're applying a control to a benchmark (even though that would make no sense).

Comment: Thanks a lot Isabel for your answer and help