# Can I use " for " instead of " as" to sound more natural / informal

Tags: word-usage, formality

Like in this example 
It's such a shame for our school to have that brazen man "for" a teacher.

Does it sound natural and used in informal language?

I mean if we say "for a teacher" instead of saying " as a teacher
Is that used in informal language ??

Comment: Your title suggests swapping in a "for" instead of an existing "as" but your example sentence would not make sense. I am not understanding your question.  Please fix your post to make it more clear.

Comment: I saw this sentence in comments on a post so I am asking about the rationale behind using " for a teacher " instead of "as a teacher".

Comment: Generally, the wording in comments on a post is not thought through carefully. I am sure that the commenter did not spend hours deciding between "for" and "as" here; they just used whichever one first popped into their mind. I don't see anything ungrammatical with either one.

Comment: This could have been a duplicate of ['As' or 'for' benchmark in a table](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/531448/as-or-for-benchmark-in-a-table), but no-one has bothered to answer that one. So I'll vote to migrate to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: _Have that man for a teacher_ sounds OK when speaking of the pupils, but not of the school.